# How to limit string permutations to just string minus one letter?

Tags: python, string, permutation

In Python, I'm trying to get permutations of a string in which just one letter is missing and the letters are not shuffled around. For example:

```
string = 'bicycle'
```

I want to get *only* these permutations:

```
['icycle','bcycle','biycle','biccle','bicyle','bicyce','bicycl']
```

Using the `permutations` module from `itertools` gives me all possible permutations, but I don't want that. What is the best way to get the permutations as shown in the list above?

Answer (score 3):

```
string = 'bicycle'

out = [string[:i] + string[i+1:] for i in range(len(string))]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
['icycle', 'bcycle', 'biycle', 'biccle', 'bicyle', 'bicyce', 'bicycl']
```

Comment: I am not sure why `'bicyce'` is not there in OP's list!

Comment: @SayandipDutta Propably typo in Op's question. Let's wait what OP says.

Comment: I've edited the question to include it, sorry for the overlook